# Excel list object reference isn't showing column names when typing a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have the very latest version of Excel 365. The problem I am facing is that when I type name of a table (list object) for constructing a formula, Excel suggests table name (like any other range name) but doesn't suggest column names.

E.g. `table_name` would be suggested when I type say `table_n`
However, when I type `table_name[` , it doesn't show column names.
It obviously showed column names every time in previous versions of Excel.

Is there any setting that I can change to get this feature back?

Comment: What is the name of the table - maybe there is an issue.

Comment: happens with every table, every excel file. I suspected that it could be some kind of memory issue but that's less likely. It happens even with just one listobject in the file

Comment: Consider [repairing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) your installation of Excel.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it now. Although I have an intuition that it won't fix it

Comment: I repaired Excel but it didn't fix it. The odd thing is that it works for simple excel files like with one sheet and 1-2 tables. When it starts to get a lot of range names, it stops showing those column names.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hit & trial, I have figured out that when table (list object) names contain a dot (e.g. table.name), it is then that the column name list doesn't show. This is regardless of the file complexity.
The alternate is that when e.g. underscore is used (table_name), the column names do show up.
It seems like a bug in Excel 365.